Thread pooling in Spring Boot
I'm new to Java and Spring Boot. This is for downloading multiple files from an SFTP server. If anything happens during the downloading, like network error or any human error, the below question can be able to do.
I'm running 3 threads and in the queue any one thread got failed. Is there any way to rerun that particular file again?
Are there any in-built methods to run those files? Any suggestion will be helpful.
public class GechubServiceImpl implements GechubService
{

    @Autowired
    private GechubConfig gechubConfig;

    @Autowired
    private GechubUtils gechubUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public void GecHubDownloader(GechubUtils gechubUtils, GechubConfig gechubConfig) {
        this.gechubUtils = gechubUtils;
        this.gechubConfig = gechubConfig;
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public String downloadFromGecHub(String fileName) throws JSchException
    {
        String response = "No File found";
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = gechubUtils.getSftpChannel();
        try
        {
            if (channelSftp != null)
            {
                channelSftp.cd(gechubConfig.getGechubOutDir());
                log.info(" Present Working Directory in Remote system -->" + channelSftp.pwd());
                List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileList = channelSftp.ls("*");
                Iterator<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = fileList.iterator();
                while (files.hasNext()) {
                    ChannelSftp.LsEntry file = files.next();
                    if (!file.getAttrs().isDir() && !file.getFilename().startsWith(".") && file.getFilename().equals(fileName)) {
                            channelSftp.get(file.getFilename(), "src/main/resources/" + file.getFilename());
                            response = "File downloaded successfully";
                            return response;
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            return "Exception occurred while getting while processing: " + e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            gechubUtils.disconnectChannel(channelSftp);
        }
    }
}

This is my class can the re-run can be implement in this process.

Of course you can do a retry loop including a time delay after each cycle, inserting it in downloadFromGecHub method, try to do domething similar changing maxRetries and Thread.sleep values:
public String downloadFromGecHub(String fileName) throws JSchException {
    String response = "No File found";
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = gechubUtils.getSftpChannel();
    int maxRetries = 3;
    int retryCount = 0;
    boolean success = false;

    while (retryCount < maxRetries && !success) {
        try {
            if (channelSftp != null) {
                channelSftp.cd(gechubConfig.getGechubOutDir());
                log.info(" Present Working Directory in Remote system -->" + channelSftp.pwd());
                List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileList = channelSftp.ls("*");
                Iterator<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = fileList.iterator();
                while (files.hasNext()) {
                    ChannelSftp.LsEntry file = files.next();
                    if (!file.getAttrs().isDir() && !file.getFilename().startsWith(".") && file.getFilename().equals(fileName)) {
                        channelSftp.get(file.getFilename(), "src/main/resources/" + file.getFilename());
                        response = "File downloaded successfully";
                        success = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while processing: " + e.getMessage());
            retryCount++;
            if (retryCount < maxRetries) {
                log.info("Retrying download... Attempt " + (retryCount + 1));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } else {
                response = "Failed to download file after " + maxRetries + " attempts";
            }
        } finally {
            gechubUtils.disconnectChannel(channelSftp);
        }
    }
    return response;
}


thanks , i think it would be helpfull for that issue

Ok, if is helpful please flag it as accepted. Thank you
